# Changing static text in a theme into variable content that also respects language. Easiest way

Tags: variables, multi-language

I bought a Theme which unfortunately has some static content, I managed to hide and remove some via editing and the custom css.

But I have a text field above the navigation where it says "Work Time" I need a way to write the German and English version of that text somewhere in my WP-Admin panel and tell the theme to load selected language text into that text field.

I have coded some stuff in php js and mysql so I'm not new to coding but **I don't know anything about coding for/in Wordpress.** I need a quick solution. What would be the best way to go about it?

I thought maybe use widgets and their content since with the Polylang Plug-in I can set widget content to specific languages.

So i basically need to place a language check there and load the according string.

Would that be the quickest way? Can anybody point me to a solution?

here's the part of the header .php I'm talking about

```
<ul class="bar">
<li class="address"><?php echo esc_html__('Work Time', 'doors') ?></li>
<li class="text_add"><?php
    $work_time = doors_get_option('work');
    if (empty($work_time)) {
        echo esc_html('');
    } else {
        echo esc_html(doors_get_option('work'));
    }
    ?></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the theme is already doing what it needs to for translation by using `esc_html__`, unless I'm misunderstanding? Recommendations for plugins are offtopic here though so you won't get a plugin recommendation for modifying `Work Time` for each language

Comment: AH ok! thats good to hear, i checked the function and you are right! The theme settings however don't provide a translated version though, does the free plugin i mentioned above have an option to add custom variables then? sorry still a noob in WP.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with polylang, I thought those plugins were aimed at translating dynamic content such as posts and pages

Comment: How is the multilanguage part being managed? Are you using a plugin to switch German/English?

Comment: Hey, yes I am using Polylang and loco translate, loco can create translations for themes by creating translation files which include all used variables by the theme. genious! And polylang provides basic translation options such as creating verisons of pages for each language and the options for languages in widgets + a switch option in the menu. hope this helps.